# Flex FileReference prohibited characters

Tags: apache-flex, filereference

The use of FileReference has a constraint on valid characters.
`Error: Error #2087: The FileReference.download() file name contains prohibited characters.`
This is fine since I guess the restriction comes from the underlying file system anyway

**Is there such a things as a generic way to trim / replace all prohibited characters?**

For clarity I am after something like:
`var dirty:String = "Eat this !@##$%%^&&*()\/";.txt`
`var clean:String = dirty.replaceAllProhibitedCharacters();`

I am not looking for OS specific regular expressions, but a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list of disallowed characters does not change depending on the underlying OS, it is a fixed list. From the documentation for `FileReference.download()` the list of disallowed characters is:

```
/\:*?"<>|%
```

**Edit:** It looks like `@` isn't allowed either.

If you want to remove those characters from an arbitrary string you can do something like this:

```
var validFileName:String = invalidFileName.replace(/[\/\\:*?"<>|%@]/g, "");
```

If you want to replace them with something else, then change the second parameter to `replace()`.

**Edit:** added the `@` character; escaped the `/` character.

Comment: I am actually invoking FileReference.save() which throws the error above. For some reason I also had to replace '@' ... Thanks for your response

Comment: Heh, I just checked the live docs for Flex 4.6 and the `save()` method has the same forbidden character list as the `download()` method... Anyway, I'm glad it solved your problem.

Comment: That regex doesn't work because some of the characters need to be escaped. Combining with the '@' needed as well, I use:

var validFileName:String = invalidFileName.replace(/\[\/\\:\*\?"<>\|%@]/g, "");

Comment: @steve only the backslash needs to be escaped. The other characters have no special meaning inside of a character class. Thanks for spotting this!

Comment: '/' must also be escaped. It's a closing char for regexp, so your code will not compile

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer did not work for me. This is what did work (Using Flex 4.5):

```
public class FileNameSanitizer
{
public static function sanitize( fileName:String ):String
{
    var p:RegExp = /[:\/\\\*\?"<>\|%]/g;
    return fileName.replace( p, "" );
}
}
```

And the testcase to prove it:

```
import flexunit.framework.TestCase;

public class FileNameSanitizerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function FileNameSanitizerTest()
    {
    }

    public function testSanitize():void
    {
        assertEquals( "bla", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla/foo" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla\\foo" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla:foo" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla*foo" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla?foo" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla\"foo" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla<foo" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla>foo" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla|foo" ) );
        assertEquals( "blafoo", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "bla%foo" ) );

        assertEquals( "", FileNameSanitizer.sanitize( "/\\:*?\"<>|%" ) );
    }

}
```